# Using Hidden Markov Models to Cluster of Time Series, trend Data?

Tags: time-series, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I have time series data of 60 observations per country, across 2 variables of interest, for 20 countries. In my case, Y depends on X, but my data is scaled. I am interested in conducting a cluster analysis with this time series data so that countries that are similar by Y are clustered together.

I found [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1660-4601/11/3/2741) that conducts a cluster analysis on time series by finding the Hidden Markov Model (HMM) of each time series, and calculating the distance between any two time series based on the similarity of the HMM probability distributions that generated them. It also allows one to consider covariates in the estimation of the HMM.

Again, my data is scaled so I'm particularly interested in clustering the data based on their trend (or shape). My question is, do I need to detrend (in differences) my data before finding the HMM for each country? I would think that detrending would cancel out the thing that I want to know about in the first place.